# How do I serial number entries on two different Google spreadsheets in chronological order?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

1. I have two Google spreadsheets.
2. The moment I enter data in a new row in the sheets, I want a serial number that's the unique and one more than the previous entry.
3. There should be no duplication of serial entries in either of the sheets.

I expect the serial number of first data entered in spreadsheet 1 to be 1, then the first data entered in spreadsheet 2 should automatically begin from 2. So on and so forth. Basically, the serial number should be dynamic.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
={"Sl No"; ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(B2:B), ROW(A1:A), ))}
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(B2:B&C2:C&D2:D), ROW(A1:A), ))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Hey there ! Thanks, but this does not resolve my problem. When data is entered in any of the columns B,C or D, I want the serial number to increase by one.

Comment: that kinda does it. did you try it?

Comment: See..  In your sheet you got 7 entries,  but the ID header shows only 5 entries you see?   My whatsapp is +91-8089610979 .  It could be great help if you can come on a chat!

Comment: Data 1 sheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vIMYCHnj-jS_bIzfenLWcBTLdLiIJJ576p-0nk9tvto/edit?usp=drivesdk
Data 2 sheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UEaMB75MASF5vuIjWcsRN7UjZrbg2la74Y6MbW1jBbA/edit?usp=drivesdk
RESULT REQUIRED SHEET
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18Zl_mSbE7MHL9JX4XScfSch3wGLGh4AMT4Y-bbDGxH4/edit?usp=drivesdk

Comment: sheets are private

Comment: Data 1 sheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vIMYCHnj-jS_bIzfenLWcBTLdLiIJJ576p-0nk9tvto/edit?usp=drivesdk
Data 2 sheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UEaMB75MASF5vuIjWcsRN7UjZrbg2la74Y6MbW1jBbA/edit?usp=drivesdk
RESULT REQUIRED SHEET
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18Zl_mSbE7MHL9JX4XScfSch3wGLGh4AMT4Y-bbDGxH4/edit?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Plz try again.  I have given editing access to you now.